# PYTHON DECLARACION FAIL

Tags: python-3.x

```
   a = 0
   e = 0
   while(a < 4):
        for e in ['uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'cuatro', 'cinco']:
            print(e)
   print(a)
   a += 1
```

Haciendo una prueba para algo, me ecuentro con esto.
por qu'e al correrlo, todo el tiempo se inicializa en cero ambas variables y entra en loooooooop?
alguien sabe?

Comment: La instrucción a +=1 está por fuera del while. Siempre tendrás `a = 0`. PD. Por favor, no uses mayúsculas sostenidas

Answer (score 0):

el problema que tienes esta en el identado.Recuerda respetar el anidado en este y cualquier otro lenguaje. Ejemplo:

```
>>> a = 0
>>> e = 0
>>> while(a < 4):
...     for e in ['uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'cuatro', 'cinco']:
...             print(e)
...     print(a)
...     a += 1
```

https://www.python.org/shell/

Answer (score 0):

Como te han comentado en otra respuesta, el problema está en la identación, print(a) y a += 1 están fuera del scope del bucle. La [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) de python, la norma de estilo para el código, dice:

> Use 4 spaces per indentation level. 
>   Continuation lines should align wrapped elements either vertically
>   using Python's implicit line joining inside parentheses, brackets and
>   braces, or using a hanging indent [7].

Además, fijate que la variable e, no tiene sentido que la inicialices a 0 antes del while, ya que después la usarás para iterar la lista dentro de éste.